# RadioGroup в ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Продублировал вопрос с англ версии сайта, так как уже давно ломаю голову над этим и буду рад любой помощи!

Необходимо добиться следующего в expandablelist:

```
РОДИТЕЛЬ 1
-Потомок 1(Радио-кнопка)
-Потомок 2(Радио-кнопка)
-Потомок 3(Радио-кнопка)
-Потомок 4(Чекбокс)
-Потомок 5(Чекбокс)

РОДИТЕЛЬ 2
...
```

НО: необходимо, чтобы радио кнопки действовали как радио-группа, т.е. нажимая на одного потомка, радио-кнопки других "расчекиваются".

Пока добился того, что нужные потомки идут с радио-кнопками, нужные с чекбоксами. Одна пока радио-кнопки не зависят никак друг от друга и можно выбрать сразу несколько.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, стандартного решения такой проблемы нет.
Но вы может в адаптере создатьмассив `int[]`, или список `List<Integer>`, в который записывать position чекнутой RadioButton для каждого родителя. И в `getChildView` проверять, если позиция чайлда соответствует позиции цекнутой кнопка в массиве, то делать ее чекнутой, иначе - не чекнутой:

```
int[]checkedButtons;
........
View getChildView(...) {
...
    radioButton.setChecked(checkedButtons[groupPosition] == childPosition);
    radiobutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...

        onCheckedChange(....) {
            if(isChecked){
                checkedButtons[groupPosition] = childPosition;
            }
        }
}
```

---

Строчку

```
radioButton.setChecked(checkedButtons[groupPosition] == childPosition);
```

Можо разложить, как

```
if(checkedButtons[groupPosition] == childPosition) {
    radioButton.setChecked(true);
} else {
    radioButton.setChecked(false);
}
```

По русски:

```
если(позиция чекнутой радиокнопки в этой группе равняется текущей позиции чайлда) {
    чекнуть текущую радиокнопку
} иначе { 
    сделать не чекнутой текущую радиокнопку
}
```

Comment: спасибо за отклик, но не понял строчку radioButton.setChecked(checkedButtons[groupPosition] == childPosition);

Comment: Благодарю,сейчас попробую, позже отпишусь

Comment: Этот способ не дал результатов ( но вероятно в этом моя ошибка). Решил сделать иным путем : вставил в xml файл RadioGroup с 3 кнопками и как бы представил, что это всё находится в одной строке ( т.е. принадлежит одному потомку). Но в итоге у всех других потомков автоматически увеличились размеры строки и пропал текст..Возможно, решение кроется в xml файле.

Comment: Вы не знаете, реально ли через xml файл это сделать?

Comment: Снова пытаюсь сделать по вашему методу, компилятор ругается на строчку radiobut.setChecked(checkedButtons[groupPosition]==childPosition);

Comment: @userpixel, через XML невозможно. Компилятор всегда ругается с сообщением.

Comment: Тогда не могли бы, пожалуйста, поподробнее описать свой замысел

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать по вашему методу, но возникает вопрос : как расчекнуть предыдущую кнопку? @metalurgus

Comment: @userpixel, строчка `radioButton.setChecked(checkedButtons[groupPosition] == childPosition);` как раз это и делает - чекает то, что надо, и разчекает то, что ненадо

Comment: попытался так сделать, в итоге чекается только первая нажатая кнопка, остальные не чекаются @metalurgus